# What is a counterexample to this statement about limits of functions?

Tags: limits, functions

I have to find an example for the condition below , I tried but i didn't find any.

$$
\lim_{x\to0} \left(f(x) + f(2x)\right) = 0 \;\not\!\!\!\implies \lim_{x\to0}f(x) = 0
$$

the function is in a deleted neighborhood of zero .

Comment: You could ensure that $f(x)+f(2x)=0$. Also please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define $f(x)$ to be $(-1)^i$ if $x=\frac{2^ia}{b}$ where $a,b$ are odd. If $x$ is irrational define $f(x)=0$.

Comment: what does the 'i' stand for?

Comment: It can be any integer. For example $i=-1$ if the rational is $1/14$.

Answer (score 5):

Say $I_n=[2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n})$, and let $$f=\sum_{n-\infty}^\infty(-1)^n\chi_{I_n}.$$Then $f(x)+f(2x)=0$.